# How to scroll onload to a section?

Tags: jquery, html

problem: its scrolling to the bottom rather than section2. maybe scrollTop isnt the way to do it? im not sure.

https://jsfiddle.net/ocoeabmy/5/

```
 var target = $("#section2");
 $('#myPanel').animate({
   scrollTop: target.offset().top - 100
 }, 700);
```

Comment: change css in all section : height: auto;

Comment: nothing happened      https://jsfiddle.net/ocoeabmy/9/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function

```
function ScrollWindowToElement(ele) {
    var sc = $(ele[0]).offset().top;
    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: (sc - 30)
    },
    'slow');
}
```

[**Your updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ocoeabmy/6/)

Comment: your solution just scrolls the window to the bottom. Instead, what should happen is the container shouldu be scrolled down to section2

Answer (score -1):

try this one:

you can remove `700` from your jquery function

```
 var target = $("#section2");
 $('#myPanel').animate({
   scrollTop: target.offset().top -100
 }, );
 //window.location.hash = "#" + "section3";
```

[**DEMO here**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/ocoeabmy/8/)

Comment: hasnt fixed anything? the scroll isnt positioned at section 2. its at the top